# org.hibernate.mappingexception: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -4

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, blob

I am not able to call `manager.find(entity)` method with an entity containing a type that is a byte[] and has a lenght greater than a tinyblob.
If i define my entity variable like this:

```
private byte[] data;
```

or like this:

```
@Column(length=200)
private byte[] data;
```

I dont' have any problems, but hibernate set the type of the column as tinyblob, too small for my purposes.

So if i try to Increase the dimension in this way:

```
@Column(length=200)
private byte[] data;
```

or even in this way:

```
@Lob
private byte[] data;
```

i get this exception `org.hibernate.mappingexception: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -4`. I tried to set various dialects in my persistence.xml but i get always the same problem :(
The exception is thrown at runtime when i call `manager.find` method, when i start the server the column is a BLOB/MEDIUMBLOB/LONGBLOB as it was supposed to be

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the bug, the exception was thrown before the method manager.find, during the calling of createNativeQuery. i had to add addScalar("data", Hibernate.BLOB)